# Nested attributes with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been racking my brain and google all morning trying to figure this out but I have come to the conclusion that I need to ask the experts! I am trying to do nested attributes with Sinatra and Angular, don't worry about the Sinatra side of things I am just trying to get the data to the server side in the correct manner at the moment. Please see the code below for an explanation of

My Input:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{item.placeholder}}" ng-model="question.possible_answer_attributes[$index][title]" class="form-control" />
```

My model object:

```
$scope.question = new Question({
  poll_id: parseInt($routeParams.id),
  title: '',
  kind: 'open',
  possible_answer_attributes: [] // I believe the issue may lie here
});
```

My factory:

```
 .factory('Question', function($resource) {
   return $resource('/api/questions/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
     'update'  : { method: 'PUT' },
     'get_by_poll' : { method: 'GET', url: '/api/questions_by_poll/:id', isArray: true }
   });
 })
```

My object at time of running save function:

```
{"poll_id"=>1, "title"=>"123123", "kind"=>"multiple", "possible_answer_attributes"=>[{"undefined"=>"412312"}, {"undefined"=>"1234124"}, {"undefined"=>"234235234"}]}
```

I do not understand why my "possible_answer_attributes" keys are coming through as "undefined". It may be something very simple that I have missed, but any feedback would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check in your browser at network tab for the response that come when the request is sent and show the response?

Comment: you don't need to use 'new' for once.  the other thing is you have an id param in your resource, but you are not passing this in as an argument in the object of Question.  Maybe poll_id should be id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to address the `title` property, you would need to use a string to index into the object:

```
ng-model="question.possible_answer_attributes[$index]['title']"
```

This should hold as long as `possible_answer_attributes` array looks like:

```
[{ title: 'my title' }]
```